# what "var { someName } = require('something')" means?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, ecmascript-6

I was reading a MDN docs about firefox addons and I saw some syntax I didn't understand.
In one of the examples they say:

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
  ...
});
```

Why is the variable name inside the braces: `var { ToggleButton } =`?

What is happening here?

Comment: If it is a firefox-addon, why did you tag `node.js`?

Comment: the firefox addons are based on node.js

Comment: firefox addons can import node modules, they are not running in a node.js environment, that's different.

Comment: so `var { someName } = require('something')` is not supported by node.js or does it not have this meaning in node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are witnessing a usage of the new ES 2015 feature called destructuring.

Refer: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#destructuring

Destructuring with Objects is supported in Firefox:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring_with_objects

**Update:**

Here is the proof.
The ToggleButton module exports `ToggleButton` object:
https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/ui/button/toggle.js#L79

And as per the ES 2015 destructuring rules, it gets destructured properly into `{ ToggleButton }`.

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why you think I am wrong?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the above code will check if we already have variable named "ToggleButton" and if is not, It will define it?

Comment: With current example, destructuring isn't much useful. It is useful when you wish to pick-n-choose multiple properties from an object with even more properties. For example: `var {name, age} = {name:'John', age:27, life:'good'};`